# JUnit Test Case is not detecting method in controller

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, testcase, spring-boot-test

New to spring boot.

API in controller looks like,

```
@RestController("/path1/path2")
public class SomeController
{

@GetMapping("/path3/path4")
public String doSomething()
{
//code goes here
}

}
```

Test case looks like,

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT, classes = 
xxx.class)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc(secure = false)
public class AuthServiceTestCase
{

@Autowired
private MockMvc mock;

@Test
public void testDoSomething()
{

//Command 1
mock.perform(get("/path1/path2/path3/path4")).andExpect(status().isOK()); 

//Command 2
 mock.perform(get("/path3/path4")).andExpect(status().isOK()); 

}

}
```

Now, after running test case (Command 1), I have got the following

"java.lang.AssertionError: Status expected:<200> but was:<404>"

But the "Command 2" succeeded as expected.

My question is,

> > RestController Prefix Path + Controller Prefix Path  = Entire Path.

For invoking an API, we have to follow above format, but why Junit fails if followed same stuff?

Could some one drop some inputs here?

Comment: Can you paste mock definition?

Comment: @Andronicus: Hi, Thx for reply. Updated the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/path1/path2")
public class SomeController
{

@GetMapping("/path3/path4")
public String doSomething()
{
//code goes here
}

}
```

The problem is not your test class. Problem is the wrong usage of requestMapping.

Comment: It worked. Thx. Could u pls explain, how (RestController Prefix Path + Controller Prefix Path = Entire Path) this pattern worked for invoking API and not for test case invocation.

Comment: @NANDAKUMAR Can you check this post ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45210005/spring-restcontroller-annotation-does-not-catch-request

Answer (score 2):

In your case `/path1/path2` is a name of a controller bean. To add a general prefix path for all methods inside controller you can put

```
@RequestMapping("/path1/path2")
```

on your controller.