# Spring boot rest api not failed in case of invalid Endpoint

Tags: spring, rest, spring-boot, spring-restcontroller

I am writing a RESTful web services using spring boot. I am using jwt bearer token for authentication an authorisation.

Below is my RestController

```
@RestController("api/v1/users")
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    UserService userService;

    @PostMapping
    public User saveUser(@RequestBody User user) {
        return userService.saveUser(user);
    }

    @GetMapping
    public List<User> getUsers(@RequestParam(required = false) String pageNumber, String pageSize, String role, String status) {
        return userService.findAll(pageNumber, pageSize, role, status);
    }

}
```

When I hit the api with request-url

```
http://localhost:8080/api/v1/users?pageNumber=0&pageSize=6&role=admin
```

Its work perfectly

but if I change the url endpoint to some invalid endpoint like

```
http://localhost:8080/api/v1/hhh?pageNumber=0&pageSize=6&role=admin
```

It still returning same results as per 1st correct endpoint.

Below are some logs statements from springframework debug logging

> Checking match of request : '/api/v1/hhh'; against
>   '/api/test/secureTest'
>
> 2019-12-28 19:16:47.601 DEBUG 5591 --- [nio-8080-exec-5]
>   o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request :
>   '/api/v1/hhh'; against 'api/authenticate'
>
> 2019-12-28 19:16:47.601 DEBUG 5591 --- [nio-8080-exec-5]
>   o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request :
>   '/api/v1/hhh'; against '/api/v1/users/me'
>
> 2019-12-28 19:16:47.601 DEBUG 5591 --- [nio-8080-exec-5]
>   o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request :
>   '/api/v1/hhh'; against '/api/v1/student'
>
> 2019-12-28 19:16:47.601 DEBUG 5591 --- [nio-8080-exec-5]
>   o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request :
>   '/api/v1/hhh'; against '/api/v1/faculty'
>
> 2019-12-28 19:16:47.601 DEBUG 5591 --- [nio-8080-exec-5]
>   o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request :
>   '/api/v1/hhh'; against '/api/v1/admin'
>
> 2019-12-28 19:16:47.601 DEBUG 5591 --- [nio-8080-exec-5]
>   o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request :
>   '/api/v1/hhh'; against '/api/v1/users'
>
> 2019-12-28 19:16:47.601 DEBUG 5591 --- [nio-8080-exec-5]
>   o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Public object -
>   authentication not attempted
>
> 2019-12-28 19:16:47.601 DEBUG 5591 --- [nio-8080-exec-5]
>   o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        :
>   /api/v1/hhh?pageNumber=0&pageSize=6&role=admin reached end of
>   additional filter chain; proceeding with original chain
>
> 2019-12-28 19:16:47.602 TRACE 5591 --- [nio-8080-exec-5]
>   o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : GET
>   "/api/v1/hhh?pageNumber=0&pageSize=6&role=admin", parameters={masked},
>   headers={masked} in DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
>
> 2019-12-28 19:16:47.602 TRACE 5591 --- [nio-8080-exec-5]
>   **o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance
>   of singleton bean 'api/v1/users'**
>
> 2019-12-28 19:16:47.602 TRACE 5591 --- [nio-8080-exec-5]
>   s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to public
>   java.util.List
>   com.asset.app.user.UserController.getUsers(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String)
>
> 2019-12-28 19:16:47.602 TRACE 5591 --- [nio-8080-exec-5]
>   .w.s.m.m.a.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod : Arguments: [0, 6, admin,
>   null]

I feel Spring cache the endpoint url and used if in case of no match found

Any Idea how to stop this?

Comment: Browsers cache the previous response if the current one fails, try opening the invalid url in another browser.

Comment: I tried it from Rest client(Postman)
And its not client cache as at the server side there is no error

Comment: Does the same happen with another browser?

Comment: yes Same behaviour with different client.
Actually call is came to controller method as I run this in debug mode.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45210005/spring-restcontroller-annotation-does-not-catch-request

Comment: You can't specify mapping in RestController, you need to use RequestMapping or other alternatives, either at class level or at method level

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you read the api documentation for [@RestController](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RestController.html)

You see that the annotation constructor takes in a `value` that is described as:

> The value may indicate a suggestion for a logical component name, to
>   be turned into a Spring bean in case of an autodetected component.

So it is used to set a name for the `Bean` that vill be created.

It is **not** used to set a url-mapping like you have done.

```
@RestController("api/v1/users")
```

You need to annotate your class with `@RequestMapping` and also add mappings to the `@PostMapping` and `@GetMapping`.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1") // Add request mapping
public class FooBar {

    @PostMapping("/users") // Add mapping here
    public User bar() {
        ...
    }

    @GetMapping("/users") // Add mapping here
    public List<User> foo() {
        ...
    }
}
```